# For which set $A$, Alice has a winning strategy?

Tags: co.combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Cross-posted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4775193/for-which-set-a-alice-has-a-winning-strategy

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They take an integer $n>1$, and partition the set $\{1,2,...n\}$ into two non-empty subsets $A,B$. Alice takes the set $A$ and Bob takes the set $B$. They take a paper and write $0$ on it. Alice plays first, and the rules are:

Each turn, let $x$ be the number written on the paper. The player has two choices:

- Erase $x$ and rewrite $0$ on the paper, or
- Choose a number $y>x$ to remove from their set, then erase $x$ and write $y$ on the paper.

The game ends if a player's set becomes empty, and that player wins the game.

**Question:** For which subsets $A$ of $\{1,2,...n\}$ does Alice have a winning strategy, and what is the number of such sets?

**Some results from MSE:**

- The natural strategy for both players: "choosing the smallest element possible that can be played from their set, except if the other player's set has only $1$ element, in which case they choose the largest element in their set" doesn't work for $n=6$, $A=\{1,4,5\}$, $B=\{2,3,6\}$, Alice wins by initially choosing $4$ or $5$, but not $1$.
- This problem is actually the simplest form of [Climbing game](https://www.pagat.com/climbing/), with no multi-card combos, for $2$ players. But I can't find any mathematic references about Climbing game.
- The number of sets $A$ such that Alice win for $n=2$ to $17$ is $2,5,9,20,41,78,162,314,630,1254,2476,4971,9806,19670,38960,77907$, and the fraction of cases won by the first player seems to converge to about $\frac{3}{5}$.

**Update:** The case $n=18,19$ the number of sets $A$ are $154948, 309081$ respectively (Karl Fabian).

---

---

---

**EDIT: a professional formulation/definition of the game.**

Let
$$X_0\cup X_1\subseteq\mathbb N,\quad X_0\ne\emptyset\ne X_1,
  \quad |X_0\cup X_1|<\infty $$
$(X_0\ X_1)$-game is a sequence of ordered pairs:

$$ ((X_n\ p_n):\ n=0...N)\qquad(\text{where}\ n\in\mathbb N) $$
where:

- $\quad X_n\ne\emptyset\ \ $ for $\ \ n<N,\quad $ and
  $\ X_N=\emptyset$;
- $\quad p_{\,0}=p_1=0;$
- $\quad$if $\ 1<n\le N\ $ then either $\ p_n=0\ $ and
  $\ X_n:=X_{n-1} or
  $$\quad p_{n-1}\le p_n\in X_{n-2} \quad\text{and}\quad
  X_n=X_{n-2}\setminus {p_n}.$$

Players Alice and Bob, one after another, control consecutive
integers $\ p_{2\cdot k}\ $ and $\ p_{2\cdot k+1}\ $ respectively.
Alice wins the game if $\ N\ $ is even, while Bob
wins if $\ N\ $ is odd.

Comment: Could you also link to some place where you enumerate the winning sets for small $n$, or share your code?

Comment: @domotorp That result is from mjqxxxx in MSE, not me.

Comment: Setting $W_n$ to be the number of sets with a first player win, then $W_n-2W_{n-1}$ goes $1, -1, 2, 1, -3, 6, -10, 2, -6, -32, 19, -136, 58, -380, -13$, which is distressingly random-looking.

Comment: Using a somewhat dense Mathematica code I can confirm the above number of winning sets for $n<18$ and get  154948, 309081  for $n=18,~19$.

Comment: This doesn't look like it would converge to 3/5, or to any other famous number I know of. @Karl Could you please link to some place where you enumerate the winning sets for small n, or share your code?

Comment: @domotorp:  Here are the $n=7$ ( 7-bit) indicators of set $B$ for winning configurations of $A$:  24$\to${0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}  $\Rightarrow\,B=\{3,4\}$:       24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 68, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 
81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126

Comment: $n=8$: 28,44,48,50,52,54,56,57,58,60,62,64,66,68,72,74,76,
80,82,84,86,88,89,90,92,94,96,97,98,100,101,102,104,
105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,
119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,130,132,136,138,
140,144,146,148,150,152,153,154,156,158,160,161,162,164,
165,166,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,
180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,
194,196,197,198,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,
210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,
224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,
238,239,240,241,...

Comment: It seems like if Alice wins without $n$, she also wins with $n$, and if she wins with $1$, she also wins without $1$.

Comment: @domotorp, [Python code and values to n=23](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/20748a527211c8b5f8851132bb3fdcee). I must say that it doesn't look to me to be converging to a constant.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't the ration monoton decreasing? Then it will converge somewhere, possibly 0.5, which would be my naive guess.

Comment: @domotorp, it's not monotonic, because e.g. the ratio for $n=15$ is larger than $n=14$, but it is monotonic between $n=15$ and $n=23$ so that could potentially be the last exception.